# Choosing specific types only from [index: string]

Tags: typescript, redux

The interface for my initial state looks like so:

```
type List = (User | Post)[];

interface InitialState {
    [index: string]: List | boolean;
    users: User[];
    posts: Post[];
    loading: boolean;
}
```

Now in my reducer, if the action type is `SPREAD_INSERT`, I change the type of `state[action.name]` (which is stored in a variable) into `List` only but the error says that it should be `List | boolean`.

```
if (action.type === 'SPREAD_INSERT') {
    const list: List = state[action.name];

    state[action.name] = [...list, ...action.payload];

    return state;
}
```

> `List | boolean` is not assignable to type `List`.

I need to know how to prevent that error. Thanks!

Comment: `state[action.name]` is of `List | boolean` type, you cannot assign it to a variable of `List` type. There is no generic answer to your question: you need to redesign your types or code to not assign incompatible values.

Comment: @zerkms I know, but what if I want to modify the users or posts only and not the `loading` state? If the action type is `SPREAD_INSERT`, the type of `state[action.name]` should be an array of users or posts, not a boolean. That's why I'm trying to change its type from `List | boolean` to `List`.